# How to apply 'Blink' feature in Ember Table?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-table

in **Ember Table**, I need to change style of a cell with the change of particular cell content.  I need to add color to cell with value update (that I have already done) and **remove styles after 1 second** (that I want to do).

I have called `setTimeout` when applying color and removed color within `setTimeout`. It does not work all the time. some cell colors are not removed.
(this gets worse when scrolling). I assume after 1 second, Ember cannot find the particular cell element.

I use and Ember table component and assigned a `contentBinding` and `columnBinding`.  I added a template for the `Ember.Table.TableCell` component and added class names.

Added Main Function and modified Jsbin example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't guarantee that this will answer your question, but here are a bunch of things that jump out at me when reading this code. I think they are best formatted as an "answer".

1. You should avoid side-effects, like calling `setTimeout`, within a computed property. Computed properties in Ember are lazy, so they only update when their value is needed. Consider using an `Observer`, or just a function, in cases like this. This is almost certainly related to your problem.
2. Instead of `setTimeout`, use `Ember.run.later` or similar Ember functions. This will make sure your code respects the Ember run loop.
3. Your `customColor` computed property doesn't depend on `previousColumnValue`, even though it uses it. This is related to the side-effects discussion: you should try to re-architect your code if possible.

Other than that, you have a lot of the right ideas. I'm fairly sure this can be done with Ember Table - the [AJAX example](http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/#/ember-table/ajax) is an example of Ember Table cells dealing with asynchrony.

I recommend debugging by first trying to create a minimal example in JS Bin, using the [Ember Table starter kit](https://github.com/addepar/ember-table#js-bin-starter-kit). This will also be useful if you'd like more help - it makes it easy for people like me to play with your setup until it works.

Comment: i posted my example and new issues faced here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071528/add-blink-feature-in-ember-table