# Add 'Blink' feature in Ember Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-table

Here are issues

- if click on an updating column (to sort) blink feature does not work.
- if i try to filter, blink feature goes crazy.

i am not sure if there are better ways to implement 'Blink'. Because i'm not sure the way i keep 'previousValue' and apply'clearStyles' method are correct.

here is the link to previous discussion. [How to apply 'Blink' feature in Ember Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747040/how-to-apply-blink-feature-in-ember-table)
Kindly add suggestions.

Comment: The JS bin is pretty complex. I will try to take a look, but it might take me a little longer. A quick comment is that your use of computed properties is still not idiomatic: CPs should not have side-effects, so e.g. your CP for "customColor" should not be setting "currentBoundValue" within its computation.

Comment: Azirbel, I really appreciate your effort on this. Yaa i agree. "currentBoundValue" is used to track removal colours. i know my way is not ideal and i seek support from you experts.

Comment: Removing "currentBoundValue" from "customColor" calculation improved blink feature. Thanks.